# ffmpeg: преобразовать аудио в звуковую волну, которая меняет цвет каждые n секунд

Tags: ffmpeg

Я пытаюсь сделать команду, которая преобразует аудио в звуковую волну, которая меняет цвет каждые n секунд.
У меня получилось только сделать, чтобы звуковая волна была случайного цвета. Пример команды:

```
ffplay -f lavfi amovie=input.wav,asplit[out0],showwaves=mode=cline:n=3:draw=full:colors=random[out1]
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы волна меняла цвет каждые n секунд, я не представляю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данный вопрос с помощью ffmpeg.